# How can I using Custom baseAdapter to display data in ListView?

Tags: android, listview, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, baseadapter

I want retrieve Data from FireBase Database and displaying it in ListView Using a custom BaseAdapter:
 I have a class Model Book:

```
 public class Book {

        String nom_livre;
        String desc_livre;
        String prix_livre;

        //Other Variables
        // getters and sitters

    }
```

Custom Adapter FeedListAdapter:

```
public class FeedListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private Activity activity;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private List<Book> feedItems;

    public FeedListAdapter( Activity activity, List<Book> feedItems) {
        this.activity = activity;
        this.feedItems = feedItems;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return feedItems.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int location) {
        return feedItems.get(location);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        if (inflater == null)
            inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        if (convertView == null)
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.feed_item, null);

        TextView name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.name_book_display);
        TextView statusMsg = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.desc_livre);
        TextView prix = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.prix_display);

        Book item = feedItems.get(position);

        name.setText(item.getNom_livre());

        if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(item.getDesc_livre())) {
            statusMsg.setText(item.getDesc_livre());
            statusMsg.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        } else {
            statusMsg.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

        if (item.getPrix_livre() != null) {
            prix.setText(item.getPrix_livre());
            prix.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        } else {
            prix.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }

        return convertView;
    }

}
```

Update Activity  :

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_accueil);
        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
        feedItems = new ArrayList<Book>();

 ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("books");
            ref.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                    for (DataSnapshot dataSnap : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

                        Book valueBook=dataSnap.getValue(Book.class);
                        String  idBookDisplay=valueBook.getId_Book();

                   if(id_user.equals(idBookDisplay)){

                       String titreLivreToDisplay=valueBook.getNom_livre();
                       String descLivreToDisplay=valueBook.getDesc_livre();
                       String prixLivreToDisplay=valueBook.getPrix_livre();
                       String timeToDisplay=valueBook.getDate_creation();
                       String filePathToDiplay=valueBook.getChemin_image();


                       Book item = new Book();

                       item.setNom_livre(titreLivreToDisplay);
                       item.setDesc_livre(descLivreToDisplay);
                       item.setPrix_livre(prixLivreToDisplay);
                       item.setDate_creation(timeToDisplay);
                       item.setChemin_image(filePathToDiplay);
                       feedItems.add(item);


                   }

                    }


                    listAdapter = new FeedListAdapter(this,feedItems);
                    listView.setAdapter(listAdapter);
                    listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

                }
 });
```

But I have this err  :

```
'FeedListAdapter(android.app.Activity, java.util.List<com.mydreambook.model.Book>)' in 'com.mydreambook.adapter.FeedListAdapter' cannot be applied to '(anonymous com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener, java.util.List<com.mydreambook.model.Book>)'
```

How can I use ValueEventListener in my custom Adapter?

Update with Source Layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:divider="@null" />

    <include
        layout="@layout/app_bar_accueil"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_accueil"
        app:menu="@menu/activity_accueil_drawer" />

</android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change

```
listAdapter = new FeedListAdapter(this, feedItems);
```

to

```
listAdapter = new FeedListAdapter(YourActivity.this, feedItems);
```

`YourActivity` is the name of `Activity` inside which you are calling `addValueEventListener`.
inside `onDataChange` method `this` == `ValueEventListener`, not an `Activity`, which is needed for `FeedListAdapter` creator

Comment: I did what you proposed to me , and i have another err :  `java.lang.NullPointerException    at Activity.onDataChange` at this line : `listView.setAdapter(listAdapter);`

Comment: like that `ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);` in onCreate()

Comment: are you setting `setContentLayout`? can you show piece of code from XML layout file? (edit you question, and more `Activity` and layout code there)

Comment: checked, nothing suspicious... I don't know why your `ListView` turns out `null` inside listener (assuming it is called inside `Activity` and `listView` declared above `onCreate`...). you probably cutted to much code ;)

Comment: this is another problem and I can't help you now, because I'm leaving for a while ;) ... ask new Question and put there more code of `Activity`, maybe someone else will help you. XML layout looks good, `findViewById` also. Good luck! :)